# vs 2008 error vsee\pkgs\vssprovider\solnutil.cpp

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have visual studio 2008 with Team Explorer 2008 installed. I used to install Team Explorer 2010 but for some reasons team explorer 2010 was uninstalled later. Then as I create a new **website project**, the vs 2008 halts, but the project was successfully created on physical disk.

I tried to select "Current Source Control plug-in " None. but the problem persists except no poping error windows.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. My profile in XP is corrupt, resetting it solved the problem.